# Quickblox Webrtc Audio Calls - Can't hear sound

Tags: javascript, jquery, webrtc, quickblox

I'm calling another user, everything seems to be working fine but I can't hear any sound when i'm talking on the microphone . 
I'm only interested in the audio calls .

A call is started when you press a button and the other user answers automatically. Here's my javascript code:

```js
(function (window, QB) {
    var CREDENTIALS = {
        appId: ,
        authKey: '',
        authSecret: ''
    };

    QB.init(CREDENTIALS.appId, CREDENTIALS.authKey, CREDENTIALS.authSecret);

    QB.createSession(function (err, result) {
        // callback function
        console.log("QB Session Created");

        var mediaParams = {
            audio: true
        };

        $("#connect").click(function () {
            var id = $('#usr').val();
            console.log("start connect");
            QB.chat.connect({ userId: id, password: "testtest" }, function (err, roster) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    console.log("USER CONNECTED");

                    $("#call").click(function () {
                        console.log("start call");
                        var calleesIds = [24853124]; //24853088
                        var sessionType = QB.webrtc.CallType.AUDIO;

                        var session = QB.webrtc.createNewSession(calleesIds, sessionType);

                        session.getUserMedia(mediaParams, function (err, stream) {
                            if (err) {
                                console.log(err);
                            } else {
                                console.log("Success get user media");

                                var extension = {};
                                session.call(extension, function (error) {
                                    if (error) {
                                        console.log(error);
                                    }
                                    else
                                        console.log("Start Call");
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    });

                }
            });
        });

        QB.webrtc.onUserNotAnswerListener = function (session, userId) {
            console.log("User didn't answer: " + userId);
        };

        QB.webrtc.onCallListener = function (session, extension) {
            console.log("Incoming Call");
            console.log('Session: ', session);
            console.log('Extension: ', extension);
            var ss = session;
            
            ss.getUserMedia(mediaParams, function (err, stream) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    console.log("Success get user media");
                    var extension = {};
                    ss.accept(extension);
                    ss.unmute('audio');
                }
            });
        };

        QB.webrtc.onAcceptCallListener = function (session, userId, extension) {
            console.log("user accepted call: " + userId);
            session.unmute('audio');
        };

    });
}(window, window.QB));
```

Log on Caller - Google Chrome:

```html
QB Session Created
app2.js:30 start connect
app2.js:36 USER CONNECTED
app2.js:39 start call
app2.js:49 Success get user media
quickblox.min.js:40 [QBWebRTC]: Call, extension: {}
quickblox.min.js:40 [QBWebRTC]: _createPeer, iceServers: {"iceServers":[{"url":"stun:stun.l.google.com:19302","urls":"stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"},{"url":"stun:turn.quickblox.com","username":"quickblox","credential":"baccb97ba2d92d71e26eb9886da5f1e0","urls":"stun:turn.quickblox.com"},{"url":"turn:turn.quickblox.com:3478?transport=udp","username":"quickblox","credential":"baccb97ba2d92d71e26eb9886da5f1e0","urls":"turn:turn.quickblox.com:3478?transport=udp"},{"url":"turn:turn.quickblox.com:3478?transport=tcp","username":"quickblox","credential":"baccb97ba2d92d71e26eb9886da5f1e0","urls":"turn:turn.quickblox.com:3478?transport=tcp"},{"url":"turn:turnsingapor.quickblox.com:3478?transport=udp","username":"quickblox","credential":"baccb97ba2d92d71e26eb9886da5f1e0","urls":"turn:turnsingapor.quickblox.com:3478?transport=udp"},{"url":"turn:turnsingapore.quickblox.com:3478?transport=tcp","username":"quickblox","credential":"baccb97ba2d92d71e26eb9886da5f1e0","urls":"turn:turnsingapore.quickblox.com:3478?transport=tcp"},{"url":"turn:turnireland.quickblox.com:3478?transport=udp","username":"quickblox","credential":"baccb97ba2d92d71e26eb9886da5f1e0","urls":"turn:turnireland.quickblox.com:3478?transport=udp"},{"url":"turn:turnireland.quickblox.com:3478?transport=tcp","username":"quickblox","credential":"baccb97ba2d92d71e26eb9886da5f1e0","urls":"turn:turnireland.quickblox.com:3478?transport=tcp"}]}
quickblox.min.js:40 [QBWebRTC]: RTCPeerConnection init. userID: 24853124, sessionID: 57f5dcc4-70d6-4c93-90c5-7793e580bfa7, type: offer
app2.js:57 Start Call
quickblox.min.js:40 [QBWebRTC]: getAndSetLocalSessionDescription success
quickblox.min.js:40 [QBWebRTC]: _startDialingTimer, dialingTimeInterval: 5000
quickblox.min.js:40 [QBWebRTC]: _dialingCallback, answerTimeInterval: 0
quickblox.min.js:40 [QBWebRTC]: onAccept. UserID:24853124. SessionID: 57f5dcc4-70d6-4c93-90c5-7793e580bfa7
app2.js:91 user accepted call: 24853124
quickblox.min.js:40 [QBWebRTC]: _clearDialingTimer
2quickblox.min.js:40 [QBWebRTC]: onIceCandidates. UserID:24853124. SessionID: 57f5dcc4-70d6-4c93-90c5-7793e580bfa7. ICE candidates count: 1
quickblox.min.js:40 [QBWebRTC]: 'setRemoteSessionDescription' success
quickblox.min.js:40 [QBWebRTC]: onIceConnectionStateCallback: checking
quickblox.min.js:40 [QBWebRTC]: onIceConnectionStateCallback: connected
quickblox.min.js:40 [QBWebRTC]: onIceConnectionStateCallback: completed
```

Log on callee - Google Canary

```html
QB Session Created
app2.js:30 start connect
app2.js:36 USER CONNECTED
quickblox.min.js:40 [QBWebRTC]: onCall. UserID:24853197. SessionID: 57f5dcc4-70d6-4c93-90c5-7793e580bfa7
app2.js:72 Apel primit
app2.js:73 Session:  
i {ID: "57f5dcc4-70d6-4c93-90c5-7793e580bfa7", state: 1, initiatorID: 24853197, opponentsIDs: Array(1), callType: 2…}
app2.js:74 Extension:  
Object {}
quickblox.min.js:40 [QBWebRTC]: _createPeer, iceServers: {"iceServers":[{"url":"stun:stun.l.google.com:19302","urls":"stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"},{"url":"stun:turn.quickblox.com","username":"quickblox","credential":"baccb97ba2d92d71e26eb9886da5f1e0","urls":"stun:turn.quickblox.com"},{"url":"turn:turn.quickblox.com:3478?transport=udp","username":"quickblox","credential":"baccb97ba2d92d71e26eb9886da5f1e0","urls":"turn:turn.quickblox.com:3478?transport=udp"},{"url":"turn:turn.quickblox.com:3478?transport=tcp","username":"quickblox","credential":"baccb97ba2d92d71e26eb9886da5f1e0","urls":"turn:turn.quickblox.com:3478?transport=tcp"},{"url":"turn:turnsingapor.quickblox.com:3478?transport=udp","username":"quickblox","credential":"baccb97ba2d92d71e26eb9886da5f1e0","urls":"turn:turnsingapor.quickblox.com:3478?transport=udp"},{"url":"turn:turnsingapore.quickblox.com:3478?transport=tcp","username":"quickblox","credential":"baccb97ba2d92d71e26eb9886da5f1e0","urls":"turn:turnsingapore.quickblox.com:3478?transport=tcp"},{"url":"turn:turnireland.quickblox.com:3478?transport=udp","username":"quickblox","credential":"baccb97ba2d92d71e26eb9886da5f1e0","urls":"turn:turnireland.quickblox.com:3478?transport=udp"},{"url":"turn:turnireland.quickblox.com:3478?transport=tcp","username":"quickblox","credential":"baccb97ba2d92d71e26eb9886da5f1e0","urls":"turn:turnireland.quickblox.com:3478?transport=tcp"}]}
quickblox.min.js:40 [QBWebRTC]: RTCPeerConnection init. userID: 24853197, sessionID: 57f5dcc4-70d6-4c93-90c5-7793e580bfa7, type: answer
quickblox.min.js:40 [QBWebRTC]: _startAnswerTimer
app2.js:82 Success get user media
quickblox.min.js:40 [QBWebRTC]: Accept, extension: {}
quickblox.min.js:40 [QBWebRTC]: _clearAnswerTimer
quickblox.min.js:40 [QBWebRTC]: 'setRemoteSessionDescription' success
quickblox.min.js:40 [QBWebRTC]: onIceConnectionStateCallback: checking
quickblox.min.js:40 [QBWebRTC]: onIceConnectionStateCallback: connected
quickblox.min.js:40 [QBWebRTC]: onIceCandidates. UserID:24853197. SessionID: 57f5dcc4-70d6-4c93-90c5-7793e580bfa7. ICE candidates count: 16
```

Am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add remote audio stream to an audio element.

Read for `onRemoteStreamListener` in [link](https://quickblox.com/developers/Sample-webrtc-web#Accept_a_call)